# Redirect to a new domain & change url structure htaccess

Tags: wordpress, .htaccess, redirect

I am trying to redirect a wordpress blog from an old domain to a new domain and changing the structure of the urls on the new domain.

So I want ***www.domainA.com to redirect*** to ***test.domainB.com/folder/***
and ***www.domainA.com/2001/12/some-post*** to redirect to ***test.domainB.com/folder/some-post***

This is what I currently have in my htaccess file. I have managed to achieve my second objective, but if you go to ***www.domainA.com***, it does not redirect to ***test.domainB.com/folder/*** All the other pages redirect properly aside from the homepage.

```
# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^([0-9]+)/([0-9]+)/(.*)$ http://test.domainB.com/folder/$3 [R=301,NC,L]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

I am sure I am missing something elemetary, but I can't seem to figure it out :(

Comment: If you want to use fake domain names, [examples](http://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc2606#section-3) are available.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this code :

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?\d+/\d+/(.*)$ http://test.domainB.com/folder/$1 [NC,L,R=301]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?domainA\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?$ http://test.domainB.com/folder/ [NC,L,R=301]

RewriteBase /
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^.*$ /index.php [L]
```